# Predictive power of a data set

Tags: regression, predictive-models, dataset

I am reading a book on machine learning for undergraduate. I am actually confused on linear regression flexibility as the say:

> Occasionally, linear regression will fail to recover a good solution for a data set. While this may be because **our data doesn’t actually have predictive power**, it might also just indicate that our data is provided in a format unsuitable for linear regression.

I read some questions here related to predictive power and I noticed that it's all about the model produced. What do we mean when we talk about the predictive power of a dataset?

I think of it as there is no relationship between features (as linear regression is intented to learn the relationship between the inputs **X** and the output **Y**). But I am not convinced of this answer yet.

Comment: The way the book words this gives me no confidence in the book.  The author seems to have not heard of regression splines, penalized regression, lasso, elastic net, ridge regression, etc.  And predictive power is not related to a _dataset_ but is related to a _model_ and how strongly the predictors are associated with the outcome variable.  And ironically the weaker the predictive power the worse machine learning works in comparison with statistical models, in many cases.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for your answer. The book was written by William J. Deuschle. Here are some additional informations to find it: Harvard College Cambridge, Massachusetts December, 2018. Hope this is another way to reference a book! The pages after this chapter present regression "methods". Reading the other answers, I was tempted to assume that this was a mistake. Due the additional information on the book I cannot  make this conclusion.